# Minimum distance for a natural satellite

Tags: gravity, planets, satellites

Is there a minimum distance between a planet and its natural satellite that should be maintained so as to keep the satellite from crashing into the planet?

Can someone explain me the physics behind how can a satellite stay so low and  orbit the planet and not crash into it due to gravitational pull of the planet?

PS: I have no physics background.  [source here](http://nineplanets.org/data.html)

Answer (score 2):

Two things affect a natural satellite: atmospheric drag, and tidal forces.

Tidal forces: As two large objects approach each other more closely, there is an ever greater difference between the gravitational attraction of the "nearby" and the "far" parts of the objects. While the objects rotate about each other, the centrifugal force will keep them from crashing into each other - but this force is stronger on the outside, while the force of gravity is weaker. The result is a force trying to pull the satellite apart. When this happens will depend on the size and mass of the objects as well as their strength.

The atmospheric drag comes into play only for planets that have an atmosphere. In the case of earth, this limits low orbit satellites to altitudes of at least 160 km ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Earth_orbit)).

In the case of a low orbit satellite, it's the high speed that prevents it from crashing. The simplest way to think about this is the approach used originally by Newton (I believe). He considered an object traveling in a straight line at a certain distance from the surface of earth. It is feeling an attraction by gravity, so it is "falling" in a parabolic orbit. But if it goes fast enough, then the next point it reaches will be the same distance from earth (because earth "curves away" as the object falls). A diagram might help explain:

[image]

For a given orbital height $r$ (measured from the center of rotation, which for simplicity we will take as the center of the bigger object although in reality two objects always "orbit each other" about their mutual center of mass or barycenter), the force of gravity attracting the two objects is

$$F_g = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

This balances the force needed to keep the object going around in a circle:

$$F_c = \frac{mv^2}{r}$$

Equating, we find the velocity to stay in orbit is

$$v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$$

Comment: is this related to the escape velocity ??

Comment: @BhagyeshChaudhari not really; the orbital velocity is a function of height; for a planet without atmosphere and with a radius $r$, an orbit grazing the surface would balance gravitational and centrifugal forces, so $\frac{GMm}{r^2}=\frac{mv^2}{r}$ which leads to $v=\sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$. The escape velocity is the surface velocity needed to escape the gravitational pull completely; equating the kinetic energy to the gravitational potential energy you get $v=\sqrt{\frac{2GM}{r}}$. Related, but different by a factor $\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a good place to start would be Newton's **Law of Universal Gravitation**
$$F = \frac{G~m_1~m_2}{r^2}$$

> Every object in the Universe attracts every other object with a force
>   directed along the line of centers for the two objects that is
>   proportional to the product of their masses and inversely proportional
>   to the square of the separation between the two objects.

This gives you an idea that there is a force established that depends on the mass of each object (the planet and its natural satellite) and the distance between them (measured from the center of the objects).

Consider now, the **1st Law of Motion: Law of Inertia**

> A body remains at rest, or moves in a straight line (*at a constant
>   velocity*), unless acted upon by a net outside force.

Because the satellite is moving in an ellipse (i.e. not a straight line -- a circle is a special case of an ellipse) around the planet,  this law states that there must be some “force” acting upon the satellite. If there were no force, the planet would fly off in a straight line.  If there were too much force it would approach the planet.

Let's now think about the **2nd Law of Motion**: 
$$F = {m~a}$$

> The acceleration of an object is proportional to the force acting upon
>   it.

The first law says that if no force is acting on an object, it will remain in motion. The second law tells how the motion will change when a force acts upon the object. Velocity is how fast an object is moving (speed or magnitude) and the direction it is moving. ***Acceleration is a change in velocity***. An accelerating object can either change how fast it is moving, the direction it is moving, or both.

Based on the aforementioned principles, you can see that there is a correlation between linear velocity, the gravity pull between the objects (planet and satellite), their masses and the distance that separates them.

Of course, the system is a little more complex if you consider that the planet and satellite are not alone, i.e., there are other satellites and planets, and let us not forget the sun.  But hopefully this will help you understand what you are asking.

References:
[Newton and planetary motion](http://astro.unl.edu/naap/pos/pos_background2.html)

Comment: Welcome, and thanks for your answer. You might want to learn about typesetting equations: on this site we use Mathjax. Your first equation could be written as `$$F = \frac{G~m_1~m_2}{r^2}$$`, for example. Removing the backticks, it renders like this $$F = \frac{G~m_1~m_2}{r^2}$$

Comment: You're welcome. See also, for example, http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a minimum distance between a planet and its natural satellite that should be maintained so as to keep the satellite from crashing into the planet?

The minimum distance in principle is the surface of the planet. In the case of the earth, the atmosphere causes air resistance which prevents satellites orbiting near to us.

> Can someone explain me the physics behind how can a satellite stay so low and orbit the planet and not crash into it due to gravitational pull of the planet?

I doubt anyone can explain the whole theory of gravity and orbits in these posts.